# how to make testing urls?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

please help correct test.

I need to test the url.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app_zapsum',
    url(r'^$', 'views.rules', name='rules'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def rules(request): 
    t = loader.get_template('page_rules.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {}) 

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from app_zapsum.views import rules
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

class TestUrls(TestCase):
    def test_details(self):
        resolver = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(resolver.rules, rules)
```

as a result of the command python manage.py test displays the following error message:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_details (app_zapsum.tests.TestUrls)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/zapsum/zapsum/app_zapsum/tests.py", line 47, in test_details
    self.assertEqual(resolver.rules, rules)
AttributeError: 'ResolverMatch' object has no attribute 'rules'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.068s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urlresolvers.resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.resolve) returns [`urlresolvers.ResolverMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.ResolverMatch) object. The object has a [`func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.ResolverMatch.func) object:

```
class TestUrls(TestCase):
    def test_details(self):
        resolver = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(resolver.func, rules)
```